# ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen2 slow charging via USB-C on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

I recently switched my ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen2 to Ubuntu 20.10.

Everything works perfectly, except it seemed to charge a bit slow.
I don't use the normal Lenovo charger usually, but rather USB-C with PD.

So I started looking into the checks for that and I confirmed that via both the sensors command as well as directly interacting with UCSI's sysfs endpoints, the negotiation doesn't seem to proceed completely correctly.
I can see the charger offers 15V or 19V, but the laptop always negotiates 5V 3A, resulting in slow 15W charging.
On Windows 10 it correctly charges with the full ~90-100W the charger permits.
Here is an example output from sensors showing the laptop even clearly see the charger's capability to use 15V:

```
root@capefox:~# sensors
...

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +15.00 V)
curr1:         3.00 A  (max =  +3.00 A)
```

Is there a way to manually tell Linux to negotiate up the voltage?

#### EDIT:

I should also mentioned I checked the typec in sysfs and verified that the mode is "usb_power_delivery" and "usb_power_delivery_revision" shows 2, so negotiation is happening, except for some reason the laptop asks for 5V 3A and never a higher voltage. I have even tried another power supply that can deliver 19V via PD, still stuck at 5V

Comment: What kernel device driver is responsible for the negotiation?

Comment: Any evidence current charger works with your laptop at full power speed?